# How to transform a coordinate system into the origin coordinate system

Tags: matlab, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation, 3d-reconstruction

I want to rotate coordinate system x such that coordinate system x is the same as the origin coordinate system ,such that a rigid object is oriented in both coordinate system the same. I do not want to rotate the object, but only want to rotate the coordinate system x.

I have two cameras 1 and 2. The camera coordinate system 1 also represents the origin coordinate system. A rigid object is captured by the camera 1 and is also displayed in the coordinate system. 
[origin coordinate system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywjb7.png)

[object points captured by camera coordinate system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yN6xt.png)

[object points captured by coordinate system x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLSr4.png)

I also have the same object displayed on  coordinate system x which unit vector I do not know. The coordinate system x is located somewhere on the line T between camera 1 and camera 2. The coordinates of the line relative to the camera coordinate system 1 is known.

How do I approach this problem?

This is to verify the 3D position of my object in camera 1. 
I know that I need to rotate the coordinate system around the axis of the origin.
Due that coordinate system x is located somewhere T, I tried to calculate the angle between origin x-axis and unknown coordinate system x before by using simple trigonometry / Pythagorean theorem. The angle I get does not deliver me the results that I want. The object is not the same way oriented in the coordinate system 1 and the unknown coordinate system.

I expect that the object is oriented the same in coordinate system x and camera coordinate system 1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align the  X Coordinate system with the Origin coordinate system, you can do a postmultiplication with the inverse of the origin coordinate system.

XCS_originCS = XCS * inv(originCS)

In this way the X coordinate system should be expressed in the origin coordinate system. Hope this works out for you

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  Is in your formula originCS the unit vector of the origin coordinate system ? Or what is specifically both the input of XCS and originCS? The output is as I understand then a transformation matrix x coordinate system with origin coordinate system

Comment: The input of the originCS and the XCS should be the orientation matricis of the coordinate systems, because the operation should be executed for the directions.

Comment: Ok, so for the case of the origin coordinate system the orientation matrix is just the identity matrix. But what if the orientation matrix of the coordinate system x is not known?